# SubDomain Routing and authentication in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, vhosts

i am creating multi tenant application in laravel 5.2 so far everything was fine but when i create subdomain routing is not working and authentication is not done so where am i wrong?

my vhost conf is like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName denly.com
    ServerAlias denly.com *.denly.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/denlyhrm/public/

    <Directory /var/www/html/denlyhrm/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

when i use test.denly.com it shows me only login page but when i submit the form blank screen appear and it is happening with all routes.

but when i use laravel server with artisan application work perfectly without sub domain.

my route is like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

i used domain parameter in route group but that also not working.

Comment: I think the problem is with the alias `ServerAlias denly.com *.denly.com` . Remove `*.denly.com` and check once.

Comment: Try to remove your main domain from `ServerAlias` leave it as `ServerAlias  *.denly.com`

Comment: i tried and remove main domain from ServerAlias but still not working